# Debugging Reconcile triggers in Kubernetes Operator

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using a custom resource in my kubernetes cluster and have built an operator (using Operator-SDK).

In my operator reconcile function, I create a secret owned by the CR and apply it on the same namespace as the CR.

Lately, I see that reconcile function is triggered for every CR instance in the cluster. This happens periodically and in strange intervals.

Could you please suggest a method of debugging why Reconcile function is triggered?

I was thinking that ideally I would monitor changes to the CR or it's owned secret, but not sure what would be the best method to do so.

Comment: Can you check the current version of Config Connector and  try updating the version. And check the RECONCILING state in the statusMessage field in cluster logs in the console.Can you provide more information about the Reconcile function you are using.

Comment: @Srividya I posted another more detailed question on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69554905/debugging-why-reconcile-triggers-on-kubernetes-custom-operator (but decided to omit some details here here since they seemed to be noisy).

Comment: By 'cluster logs', do you mean logs collected from pods running in the cluster into a centralized location? If so, I don't have it implemented and am not sure what I'd be looking for in these logs. Could you please explain how I'd be getting the cluster log you mentioned?

Comment: I also don't know that I'm using a 'Config Connector'. I simply applied the CRD with the spec of the resource I need, then deployed the operator I created with Operator-SDK.